# Raycasting involving individual points in a Three.js PointCloud

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a `PointCloud` object that displays several points.  I'd like to be able to draw a bounding box around the clicked point.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to access the individual point within the `PointCloud`, if this is even possible.

This is the raycasting code I'm using...

```
window.addEventListener('dblclick', function (ev) {
    var mouse = { x: 1, y: 1 };
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold = 15;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5).unproject(camera);
    raycaster.ray.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(particles);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        console.log(intersects[0]);
        var hex  = 0x000000;

        var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(intersects[0], hex);
        bbox.update();
        scene.add( bbox );

    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
);
```

I can access the coordinates of the clicked point using `intersects[0].point.x`.  But passing `intersects[0]` to `BoxHelper` obviously doesn't work because `intersects[0]` is not an `Object3D`.  Likewise, if I use `intersects[0].object`, this draws a box around the entire `PointCloud`, whereas I'd like it just around the clicked point.

Is this possible, and if so, how might I go about doing it?

Thanks very much for any assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check these examples, they will help you working with particle/point clouds:

[webgl_interactive_particles](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_particles) and [webgl_interactive_raycasting_pointcloud](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_raycasting_pointcloud).

With `intersects[0].index` you can find the index of the point you intersected. So you can use this index to find your point:

```
var index = intersects[0].index;
var point = particles.geometry.vertices[ index ];
```

Like you already said to be able to draw a `BoundingBox` you need an `Object3D`. A single particle is only a point in space so drawing a `BoundingBox` around that point would actually be a box with size 0. So with that part I cannot help you.